# Ruby Time.zone.now and accounting for database precision

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a test in a Rails 3 test suite that makes a number assertions that compare timestamps that passes on my local machine but fails within our CI pipeline.  This test stores a timestamp in a Postgres database timestamp field with the precision of 6 and compares the stored value to the original timestamp, very similar to the following example:

```
tmp_time = Time.zone.now
u = User.find(1)
u.updated_at = tmp_time
u.save!
u.reload

assert_equal u.updated_at.to_i, tmp_time.to_i # passes...
assert_equal u.updated_at, tmp_time # fails...
assert_equal u.updated_at.to_f, tmp_time.to_f # fails...
```

I believe the problem relates to Ruby's time representation being of a higher precision than the stored value.

What is the best way of compensating for the slight difference in values due to precision, outside of being less precise in comparisons?  We have considered overriding Time.zone.now, but believe that will lead to downstream problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What could possibly be the usefulness of this test in the first place?  Seems like you don't trust timestamps.

Comment: Can you output the values of `u.updated_at.to_f` and `tmp_time.to_f` in your CI pipeline?

Comment: _"passes on my local machine but fails within our CI pipeline"_ – If this is due to Postgres you should have the same problem on your local machine. Or do you run different Postgres versions / database schemas locally and on your CI?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `.save!` an actual write to the database occurs. Timestamps are written by the database which updates the actual data stored in `updated_at` which is not written by the ActiveRecord Ruby object (unless you do so explicitly with `u.update_attribute(updated_at: tmp_time)` which defeats the point of timestamps in most cases.

So the time in memory at the moment you instantiate the Ruby `Time` object won't match the time recorded by the database, which will be some nanoseconds later.  Converting `Time.new.to_i` is not very accurate. While `.to_f` is normally "close enough", equality of time is nearly impossible.  This can be illustrated with a multi-threaded example:

```rb
@times = []
def test_time
  t1 = Thread.new{ @times << Time.now }
  t2 = Thread.new{ @times << Time.now }
  t1.join; t2.join
end
test_time

puts @times.each(&:to_s)
# they may appear the same depending on default `.to_s` format
# 10/29/2021 2:20PM
# 10/29/2021 2:20PM

@times.map(&:to_i)
=>[1635531636,1635531636] # same problem

@times.map(&:to_f)
=>[1635531636.989422, 1635531636.989532] # here's often enough precision but... 

# under the hood times[1] == times[2] will use the most precise nsec method
@times.map(&:nsec)
=>[989422129, 989531969]
```

See also [See docs on Time#nsec](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-nsec)

Comment: How does freezing the time help here? The current time is retrieved **only once** and referred from a local variable from there, which doesn't change.

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran I've updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably not with precision in the database, but rather that a small time passes between when you define `tmp_time` and when you save.

You can see that the `.to_f` representation of Time changes instantly:

```
irb(main):011:0> 2.times.map { Time.now.to_f }
=> [1551755487.5737898, 1551755487.573792]
```

This difference is usually not visible when you use `.to_i` because it rounds to the nearest second.

You can use [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop), as another answer mentions, to get around this:

```
irb(main):013:0> Timecop.freeze { 2.times.map { Time.now.to_f } }
=> [1551755580.12368, 1551755580.12368]
```

Comment: `Time.zone.now` is used only once in OP's test, not twice as in your example. OP is storing it in a variable and referencing it as a constant which doesn't change through the course of the assertions.

Comment: Its called internally when you save, to determine updated_at

Comment: Ah right. Gotcha. So the issue is we cannot set `updated_at` ourselves. Rails always overrides them.

Comment: @LeninRajRajasekaran that may not be true. `u.save!` doesn't override the manually set timestamp, which is bad practice anyway.  In fact this whole test seems pointless unless it's uncovering some core rails bug none of us are aware of.

Comment: @lacostenycoder you're right that this test seems pointless, but there are valid use cases for locking tests at a point in time.